# Filter rows based on unique condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter, conditional-statements

I have the following dataframe that represents the employee number, the department they are and their code.

```
   Department Name     Employee Number      Role Code   
0  Dept1               1000                     1
1  Dept1               1000                     2
2  Dept2               1000                     2
4  Dept3               1000                     2
5  Dept4               1000                     1
0  Dept1               1001                     1
1  Dept2               1001                     1
2  Dept2               1001                     2
4  Dept3               1001                     1
5  Dept3               1001                     2
```

I need to filter this dataframe in a way that each employee can have only the code 1 OR the code 2 in each unique department. If they have both roles in the same department, return both rows, so this output:

```
   Department Name     Employee Number      Role Code   
0  Dept1               1000                     1
1  Dept1               1000                     2
1  Dept2               1001                     1
2  Dept2               1001                     2
4  Dept3               1001                     1
5  Dept3               1001                     2
```

What would be the best way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
df.groupby(['Department Name','Employee Number']).filter(lambda x: x['Role Code'].nunique() == 2)
```

```
  Department Name  Employee Number  Role Code
0           Dept1             1000          1
1           Dept1             1000          2
6           Dept2             1001          1
7           Dept2             1001          2
8           Dept3             1001          1
9           Dept3             1001          2
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's try `groupby().nunique()`:

```
mask = df.groupby(['Department Name','Employee Number'])['Role Code'].transform('nunique')

df[mask==2]
```

Output:

```
  Department Name  Employee Number  Role Code
0           Dept1             1000          1
1           Dept1             1000          2
1           Dept2             1001          1
2           Dept2             1001          2
4           Dept3             1001          1
5           Dept3             1001          2
```